# ¿Cómo puedo llegar a cierta información de una API?

Tags: html, typescript, api

Estoy trabajando con una api y no sé como llegar a la información del apartado 'harvests' en mi página web, si alguien sabe por favor que me diga como funciona esto,  he llegado hasta poder recoger la información de apartado en general, pero no sé como adentrarme más en la api hasta poder coger lo que hay dentro del apartado 'harvests'.
URL DE LA API: https://fr.dofus.dofapi.fr/professions

IMG DEL APARTADO DE LA API:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
HTML oficio (esta sale bien, es la información general):

```
<div class="bg-dark border border-2 mt-4 mb-5 px-5 pb-5 bg-opacity-50" style="width: 100em">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
      <div class="text-light text-center" [routerLink]="'/oficio/' + miOficio._id">
        <h1>{{miOficio.name.toUpperCase()}}</h1>
        <img src="{{miOficio.imgUrl}}">
        <p>{{miOficio.description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark border border-2 mt-4 mb-5 px-5 pb-5 bg-opacity-50" style="width: 100em">
  <div class="text-light m-2 mt-5 text-center">
    <h3>RECOLECCIÓN</h3>
    <p>(La recolección es lo que se podrá recoger para subir de nivel el oficio, si está vacio es porque no tiene recolección, son oficios de creación).</p>
    <div class="container-fluid p-3 text-light" style="width: 80%">
      <table class="table table-hover table-dark border border-light">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Material</th>
          <th scope="col">Nivel necesario</th>
          <th scope="col">Imágen</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let harvest of miOficio.harvests">
        <tr [routerLink]="'/oficio/' + miOficio._id + '/' + harvest.ankamaId">
          <td class="p-2 px-4">{{harvest.name}}</td>
          <td>{{harvest.level}}</td>
          <td><img src="{{harvest.imgUrl.slice(4)}}" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TYPESCRITP oficio:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-oficio',
  templateUrl: './oficio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oficio.component.css']
})

export class OficioComponent implements OnInit {
  miOficio: Oficio = {
    _id: 0,
    ankamaId: 0,
    name: '',
    level: null,
    imgUrl: '',
    url: '',
    description: '',
    harvests: [],
    recipe: []
  }

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private oficioService: OficioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadOficio();
  }
  private loadOficio(){
    const parametros = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    this.oficioService.getOficio(parametros['id2']).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.miOficio = data;
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

HTML recolección:

```
<div class="bg-dark border border-2 mt-4 mb-5 px-5 pb-5 bg-opacity-50" style="width: 100em">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
      <div class="text-light text-center">
        <h1>Hola</h1>

        <!--<h1>{{miMaterial.name}}</h1>
        <img src="{{miMaterial.imgUrl}}">
        <p>{{miMaterial.location}}</p>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TYPESCRITP recolección:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recoleccion',
  templateUrl: './recoleccion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recoleccion.component.css']
})

export class RecoleccionComponent implements OnInit {

  miMaterial: Harvest = {
    imgUrl: '',
    name: '',
    url: '',
    ankamaId: 0,
    level: 0,
    location: []
  }
  miOficio: Oficio = {
    _id: 0,
    ankamaId: 0,
    name: '',
    level: null,
    imgUrl: '',
    url: '',
    description: '',
    harvests: [],
    recipe: []
  }
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private oficioService: OficioService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRecoleccion();
  }

  private loadRecoleccion(){
    const parametros = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    this.oficioService.getOficio2(parametros['id2'],parametros['id3']).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        var atun = parametros['id3'];
        this.miOficio.harvests = data;
        console.log(this.miOficio.harvests)  <!--Esto no me printea nada-->
      }
    )
  }
}
```

El parámetro 'id2' es el id que tiene  el propio componente oficio, y el parámetro 'id3' es el id que tiene el 'harvest' del cual quiero recoger la información para poder llamarla en el html.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso que mostras en una imagen, es un json... no vas a poder acceder desde la URL a ese elemento. No funciona asi...

Comment: @gbianchi, y  desde el typescript se puede llegar? perdona, es que no tengo casi idea de como funciona esto, me han dado una clase vagamente y explicando lo justo y necesario para que su api funcionara.

Comment: múestranos tu código con el que consigues "poder recoger la información de apartado en general"; así podremos indicarte mejor como seguir

Comment: @PA. ya te he puesto, creo que ya, si necesitáis algo más decirme. Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: Typescript es javascript, pero tipado.. o sea que si podes con uno, podes con el otro.. desgraciadamente, en todas esas imagenes (que son muy dificiles de ver, no uses imagenes), no hay ni una gota de typescript por ningun lado.... o esa... no hay codigo js en ningun lado...

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: y estas trabajando en angular.. no en ts.. y no hay ni una gota de angular en tus otros componentes...

Comment: Bien @gbianchi, espero haber puesto bien el código,  perdona por lo anterior y gracias por decírmelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO EN EL TYPESCRITP DE RECOLECCIÓN:

```
export class RecoleccionComponent implements OnInit {

  miMaterial: Harvest = {
    imgUrl: '',
    name: '',
    url: '',
    ankamaId: 0,
    level: 0,
    location: []
  }

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private oficioService: OficioService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRecoleccion();
  }

  private loadRecoleccion() {
    const parametros = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    this.oficioService.getOficio(parametros['id2']).subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      var atun = parametros['id3'];

      for (let datas of  data.harvests) {
        console.log('Atún: ' + atun)
        console.log(datas.ankamaId);
        if (datas.ankamaId == atun){
          console.log('Hola');
          this.miMaterial = datas;
        }
      }
    }
  )
  }
}
```

Lo nuevo ha sido utilzar el bucle for para comprobar todos los id con el parámetro de entrada que es el id, y ya cuando lo encuentre guardar la información, entonces en el html ya puedo coger esa información.